# Corona sdk attempt to compare number with string error message

Tags: string, sdk, numbers, compare, coronasdk

I keep getting an error message "Attempt to compare number with string" message. The variables  contain floating point numbers. Any suggestions on how to get around this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Unless you provide the code that's causing the error, we really can't help you...  Have you printed the values **right** before the line that causes the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cant compare number with the string

You can try this

```
 local value = tonumber("100") --need to convert it to number
 if value < 10 then 
      --do something
 end
```